# Ip spoofing is possible? Can a linux VPS spoof ip's?

Tags: linux, networking

I own myself 1 website and 1 application with api's.
I would like to test what I've read about ipspoofing as I'd like to implement an IP-Login feature.
But as long as I've searched I didn't find any company which allow ipspoofing for pentesting, and spoofing locally on my ISP seems impossible from what i've read.
Also, is it possible to extabilish a connection with a website/server and just sending packets with instructions without receiving a response?
I have a server A
Im B, and an user is C
can I send a connection command C-A and then send a command like 'Buy something' or even 'Logout'?

Comment: IP spoofing is possible but only under limited circumstances, and in those cases you are generally looking at a problem in segments of your internal network, or in the networks immediately upstream from yours. generally attacks using IP spoofing are either blind (eg they don't expect response traffic) or are also manipulating network infrastructure at Layer 2 (attacker uses ARP attacks to isolate a machine, forces the switch into promisc mode, and allows the attacker to intercept and respond to traffic addressed to the now isolated machine, in effect masquerading as them).

Answer (score 0):

IP spoofing is possible for UDP packet from VPS, through it should not. But so far as I know it is not possible to create spoofed tcp connection because of 3 way handshake process. So spoofed tcp packets with 'Buy something' will not be possible. But you can send spoofed RST packet and close connection